# expressjs app specified wrong router path

Tags: express, nginx

My express application runs on the host, sometimes I see the syslog showing the following message:
[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4h2F.png)

but the application's router is:

```
router.get('/api/cart/products',PublicController.browse);
```

here is the application static path setting:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

i don't know why nginx is routing wrong path to public static directory.
Can anyone help me figure out what is the cause? thanks a lot?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing more code or the structure of your folders. If you don't have the second line

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

at the very end (it must come last after every other route) you will face issues. Have you made sure that this line of code comes after all your other routes?